# Can't let a script parse the rest of the results that appear after a certain text

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a script in python to scrape the title and link of different  post from a webpage when it meets a certain condition. I want the script to print the rest of the results that are available after a certain text, as in `Alternative to Chromedriver` in this case. However, my current attempt (faulty) only prints this text `Alternative to Chromedriver`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=Newest"
check_title = "Alternative to Chromedriver"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
    if check_title!=item.get_text(strip=True):continue
    title = item.get_text(strip=True)
    link = item.get("href")
    print(title,link)
```

How can I let the script parse the rest of the results that appear after a certain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=Newest"
check_title = "Alternative to Chromedriver"

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

# Initialise a flag to track where to start printing from 
start_printing = False

for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
    title = item.get_text(strip=True)

    # Keep iterating until the required text is found. Initialise it only once
    if not start_printing and check_title == title:
        start_printing = True
        continue
    if start_printing:
        link = item.get("href")
        print(title,link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the `ì` statement: "If the title is not `Alternative to Chromedriver` then continue loop the next title", that's why it only prints out when your `title == 'Alternative to Chromedriver'`. To print all `titles`, change the code like this

```
for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
    title = item.get_text(strip=True)
    link = item.get("href")
    if check_title == title:
        print(f'Found it: {title}, {link}')
    else:
        print(title,link)

#Web scrapting of image with Python /questions/61035199/web-scrapting-of-image-with-python
#Imported functions not working in puppeteer /questions/61035043/imported-functions-not-working-in-puppeteer
#Trying to build a webscraper following a tutorial and keep getting attribute error for findall /questions/61034690/trying-to-build-a-webscraper-following-a-tutorial-and-keep-getting-attribute-err
#Python Selenium Web Scraping Hidden Div /questions/61034439/python-selenium-web-scraping-hidden-div
#Found it: Alternative to Chromedriver, /questions/61034224/alternative-to-chromedriver
```

Look at the output above, the last one has `title` euqal to `'Alternative to Chromedriver'`, so it prints out `'Found it'`, others just print `title, link`